# How can I do an orderBy query for data that is stored in JSON format?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

So for example when the data is in string format I can do something like this:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(animal_type, "fish", "amphibian", "reptile", "bird", "mammal", "") ASC, animal_type'))
```

But if the data for 'animal_type' is stored in JSON format like this:

```
["vertebrate", "amphibian"]
```

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

| id | animal | animal_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Leaf green tree frog | ["vertebrate", "amphibian", "ectothermic", "pelodryadidae"] |
| 2 | Seymouria | ["vertebrate", "amphibian"] |
| 3 | Dermophis mexicanus | ["amphibian"] |
| 4 | Old World sparrow | ["vertebrate", "bird"] |
| 5 | Parrot | ["vertebrate", "bird", "psittacines"] |
| 6 | African bush elephant | ["vertebrate", "mammal"] |

Ideally I'd like to sort by a single characteristic of the animal. Say order by "bird", "amphibian". Then the result would look like:

```
Old World sparrow
Parrot
Leaf green tree frog
Seymouria
Dermophis mexicanus
```

How would I go about creating a query that can do an orderBy in this kind of scenario?

Comment: What would be the result of sorting by animal_type if it has an array of values?

Comment: It would just sort like the string variation. Like all the fish first, amphibians second, and so on and so forth. Ideally I would be able to choose which part of the json data it would sort by since the json data could have more than one animal characteristic.

Comment: But in your example, '["vertebrate", "amphibian"]', a stored in a single row. That's what JSON is for. So if a single row is both a vertebrate and an amphibian, what does it mean to sort that row by multiple values? Can you show an example?

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 introduces a JSON function that can help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of

Here's how it works:

```
mysql> select * from mytable order by 
  'bird' member of(animal_type) desc, 
  'amphibian' member of(animal_type) desc;
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | animal                | animal_type                                |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|  4 | Old World sparrow     | ["vertebrate", "bird"]                     |
|  5 | Parrot                | ["vertebrate", "bird", "psittacines"]      |
|  1 | Leaf green tree frog  | ["vertebrate", "amphibian", "ectothermic"] |
|  2 | Seymouria             | ["vertebrate", "amphibian"]                |
|  3 | Dermophis mexicanus   | ["amphibian"]                              |
|  6 | African bush elephant | ["vertebrate", "mammal"]                   |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Although MySQL 8.0 also supports creating a multi-valued index on JSON data to help searches for values, this only helps optimize row filtering (WHERE clause), it does not yet optimizing sorting (ORDER BY clause).

If you use a version of MySQL 5.x that doesn't support `MEMBER OF()`, you're out of luck. You should be making plans to upgrade anyway, because 5.x is going to be end of life in October 2023.

Comment: The good news is I am using MySQL 8.0. Is there a way to make it more in the Laravel format?

Comment: I have no idea about Laravel. I'd guess you should use `orderByRaw()` when you have to order by an expression.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the detailed reply. This is really close. I gave you an upvote. Let's see if anyone else can provide a better answer.